# Create list of AJAX type links to be googled by appliance

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

We have a large collection of web content that we want to make searchable by Google Appliance but have a fairly complex list of what we want and don't want included.  Because a lot of the content is AJAX like, just having Google do the searching isn't a solution.  Instead, we have a classic ASP page that loops through all of our directories and files using the Scripting.FileSystemObject  and excludes/includes files/folders and generates a large list of hyperlinks in a page that Google can then query.  This process is painfully slow  (20 minutes or more) but now we are able to move this process on Dot Net server.

I'm doing a little bit of exploring wondering what solutions people may have found useful for this kind of thing.  We're exploring Microsoft.Web.Administration and anything else that will make this more efficient including writing the resulting list to a html file.

Does anyone with experience with this have any suggestions as to how to approach this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/admin_crawl/Preparing#robotscs, the Appliance Server obeys robots.txt.  You should be able to that to the root of the site and configure it to disallow indexing of particular folders or extensions.

Comment: Thank you.  We are aware of that, but that completely misses the point.  The reason many people including ourselves, use AJAX is because of dynamically generated content - which doesn't crawl very well if you are looking for the final merged content.

Comment: Have you investigated http://crawljax.com/?  I'm not familiar with it, but it looks like it may be a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you.  That's a pretty cool tool.  We ended up modifying our .asp page and adding more rules to our Google appliance using robots.txt.

Comment: Sure -- Hope it helps.  An alternative to the classic ASP page might be to create a .NET console app to iterate your file system in a similar manner and generate a static HTML page(s) which the GAS could index.  It's been my experience that the .NET classes for interacting with the file system are easier to use and more efficient than `Scripting.FileSystemObject`

Comment: That was really what I was looking for.  My assumption was that a compiled app would be much faster than a .asp page.  Thank you again.